# Has GCC13 changed handling of noexcept function pointers?

Tags: c++, gcc, language-lawyer, noexcept

I have a trait to determine the class of a member function pointer.

In GCC12, it works for both `const` and `const noexcept` function pointers.

In GCC13, it no longer works. Clang 16 and MSVC agree with GCC12. If I add a `noexcept` specialisation, it fixes GCC12, and breaks GCC12/Clang/MSVC.

Is this behaviour specified in the C++ Standard, or is this a GCC bug?

If this is expected behaviour, how can I support both GCC12 and GCC13?

```
#include <type_traits>

template <auto>
struct get_class;

template <typename Ret, typename Klass, typename... Args, Ret (Klass::*FN)(Args...) const>
struct get_class<FN> : public std::type_identity<Klass>
{};

// Uncomment this to fix GCC13, and break everyone else...
//template <typename Ret, typename Klass, typename... Args, Ret (Klass::*FN)(Args...) const noexcept>
//struct get_class<FN> : public std::type_identity<Klass>
//{};

class MyClass {
public:
    int func1() const noexcept {return 0;}
    int func2() const {return 0;}
};

int main(){
    [[maybe_unused]]get_class<&MyClass::func1>::type x = MyClass{};
    [[maybe_unused]]get_class<&MyClass::func2>::type y = MyClass{};
}
```

Live example: https://godbolt.org/z/YGv8hxPWd

Comment: Yes you need a specialization for noxecept signatures too. See : https://godbolt.org/z/ET5cjbP3v

Comment: Hmm, I'm getting the feeling I misunderstood this so I'm removing my answer. [Here's why](https://godbolt.org/z/qzMxarTdT)

Comment: cleaner godbolt https://godbolt.org/z/fPEhW6cbf

Comment: When trying specialize for other types of member functions: gcc 13 works everything else fails: https://godbolt.org/z/b4as465zK

Comment: May relate to [CWG2355](https://cplusplus.github.io/CWG/issues/2355.html), which however GCC marked as implemented already from GCC 12.

Comment: I'm suspecting that the GCC delta between GCC 12 and GCC 13 is unrelated to the Clang/MSVC/GCC implementation variance shown by the example: the latter seems to have existed already in earlier GCC version ([DEMO](https://godbolt.org/z/8K8sqEE5f)), however OP's demo moreover introduces something that adds a delta between GCC versions.

Comment: Thanks all, I've incorporated Marek's godbolt into the question. I've also highlighted that simply adding a `noexcept` specialisation breaks everybody except GCC13, which is sad.

Answer (score 2):

Based on this:

[noexcept specifier (since C++11) - cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/noexcept_spec)

> The noexcept-specification is not a part of the function type (just
> like [dynamic exception
> specification](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/except_spec)) and can only appear as a part of a
> [lambda declarator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) or a top-level [function
> declarator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function) when declaring functions, variables,
> non-static data members of type function, pointer to function,
> reference to function, or pointer to member function, and also when
> declaring a parameter or a return type in one of those declarations
> that in turn happens to be a pointer or reference to function. It
> cannot appear in a
> [typedef](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typedef) or [type
> alias](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias) declaration.
>
> ```cpp
> void f() noexcept; // the function f() does not throw
> void (*fp)() noexcept(false); // fp points to a function that may throw
> void g(void pfa() noexcept);  // g takes a pointer to function that doesn't throw
> // typedef int (*pf)() noexcept; // error
> ```
>
> (until C++17)
>
> ---
>
> The noexcept-specification is a part of the function type and may
> appear as part of any [function
> declarator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function). (since C++17)

So in C++17 when `noexcept` is part of function type, then template specialization should take it into account. So looks like gcc 13 is right and other compilers are wrong.

I've also found something like this:
https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4533.html

On other hand there is code compatibility issues, so I would not be surprised this could be controlled by some compilation flag (and different default behavior was selected). I would recommend review compiler documentation about this.

**Disclaimer** I'm not language lawyer so maybe someone can provide better information.

Comment: Yeah, I thought that cppreference link was the smoking gun. But the relevant paper seems to be [P0012R1](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0012r1.html), a later revision of N4533, which was in GCC7. I'm struggling to track down any relevant changes in GCC13 that would change this behaviour. As you identified, the tricky bit is that fixing GCC13 breaks everyone else, and I have to support both GCC12 and GCC13.